# How to convert code to more readable form in R

Tags: r

I copy code from the terminal to post here. It is in following form:

```
> ddf2 = ddf[ddf$stone_ny>'stone',] # this is first command
> ddf2[!duplicated(ddf2$deltnr),]   # second command
   deltnr us stone_ny stone_mobility      
4    1536 63    stone         mobile 
10   1336 62    stone         mobile
```

First 2 lines are commands while next 3 lines are output. However, this cannot be copied from here back to R terminal since the commands start with '> '. How can I convert this to:

```
ddf2 = ddf[ddf$stone_ny>'stone',] # this is first command
ddf2[!duplicated(ddf2$deltnr),]   # second command
#   deltnr us stone_ny stone_mobility      
#4    1536 63    stone         mobile 
#10   1336 62    stone         mobile
```

So that it become suitable for copying from here.

I tried:

```
text
[1] "> ddf2 = ddf[ddf$stone_ny>'stone',] # this is first command\n> ddf2[!duplicated(ddf2$deltnr),]   # second command\n   deltnr us stone_ny stone_mobility      \n4    1536 63    stone         mobile \n10   1336 62    stone         mobile "


text2 = gsub('\n','#',text)
text2 = gsub('#>','\n',text2)
text2 = gsub('#','\n#',text2)
text2
[1] "> ddf2 = ddf[ddf$stone_ny>'stone',] \n# this is first command\n 
ddf2[!duplicated(ddf2$deltnr),]   \n# second command\n#   deltnr us stone_ny stone_mobility      \n#4    1536 63    stone         mobile \n#10   1336 62    stone         mobile "
```

But it cannot get pasted to the terminal.

Comment: If you're using RStudio, you can easily write your code in the script editor area and comment out the results with Ctrl + Alt + C.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+C does not work in my system (R studio 0.98.501 on Linux Debian stable)

Comment: also, you might want to have a look at `Sublime Text 3` + `Enhanced R package` (for ST3).  Multi-line editing is incredible

Comment: I think it's actually Ctrl + Shift + C, or using the menus Code > Comment / Uncomment Lines.

Comment: If you are using the usual Rgui interface to R on Windows then copy the code together with the `>` marks to the clipboard and then in Rgui choose `Edit` and then `Paste commands only`.  Note that many people posting on SO post their code without the `>` and put `##` marks in front of output lines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been waiting for an opportunity to share this function I keep in my `.Rprofile` file. While it may not answer exactly your question, I feel it is accomplishing something very close to what you are after. So you might get some ideas by looking at its code. And others might find it useful just as it is. The function:

```
SO <- function(script.file = '~/.active-rstudio-document') {

   # run the code and store the output in a character vector
   tmp <- tempfile()
   capture.output(
      source(script.file, echo = TRUE, 
                          prompt.echo = "> ",
                          continue.echo = "+ "), file = tmp)
   out <- readLines(tmp)

   # identify lines that are comments, code, results
   idx.comments <- grep("^> [#]{2}", out)
   idx.code     <- grep("^[>+] ", out)
   idx.blank    <- grep("^[[:space:]]*$", out)
   idx.results  <- setdiff(seq_along(out),
                           c(idx.comments, idx.code, idx.blank))
   # reformat
   out[idx.comments] <- sub("^> [#]{2} ", "", out[idx.comments])
   out[idx.code]     <- sub("^[>+] ", "    ", out[idx.code])
   out[idx.results]  <- sub("^", "    # ", out[idx.results])

   # output
   cat(out, sep = "\n", file = stdout())
}
```

This `SO` function is what allows me to quickly format my answers to questions on this very website, StackOverflow. My workflow is as follows:

1) In RStudio, write my answer in an untitled script (that's the top-left quadrant). For example:

```
## This is super easy, you can do

set.seed(123)
# initialize x
x <- 0
while(x < 0.5) {
   print(x)
   # update x
   x <- runif(1)
}

## And voila.
```

2) Near the top, click the "Source" button. It will execute the code in the console which is not really what we are after: rather, it will have the side effect of saving the code to the default file '~/.active-rstudio-document'.

3) Run `SO()` from the console (bottom-left quadrant) which will source the code (again...) from the saved file, capture the output and print it in a SO-friendly format:

```
This is super easy, you can do

    set.seed(123)
    # initialize x
    x <- 0
    while(x < 0.5) {
       print(x)
       # update x
       x <- runif(1)
    }
    # [1] 0
    # [1] 0.2875775

And voila.
```

4) Copy-paste into stackoverflow and done.

Note: For code that takes a while to run, you can avoid running it twice by saving your script to a file (e.g. 'xyz.R') instead of clicking the "Source" button. Then run `SO("xyz.R")`.

Comment: This is really cool, thanks for sharing it.  When I run it though, I get comment characters in front of `print(x)` all the way down to `[1] 0.2875775`  Do I need to adjust something?

Comment: Hmm. Are you using the default prompts (`"> "` and `"+ "`)? You can check by running `getOption("prompt")` and `getOption("continue")`. My function can be made more robust by adding `prompt.echo = "> "` and `continue.prompt = "+ "` to the `source()` call. I'll add that regardless.

Comment: well, as you see, when I reformat, I am assuming the prompt is "> ". So either I can call `source` with the default `prompt.echo = getOption("prompt")` but I need to use `getOption("prompt")` in my regex, or I force using `"> "` by adding `prompt.echo = "> "` to the source call. I went for the latter, see my edit.

Comment: I'm most curious to know if you produced this entire answer with your function. :)

Comment: We need to go deeper!

Comment: @flodel: Great function. Ideally, it should be incorporated in the stackoverflow webpages so that the text can be pasted straight from R terminal to stackoverflow.

Comment: @rnso, halfway there... how to paste into the text box? http://bit.ly/so_functions

Answer (score 2):

You could try `cat` with an `ifelse` condition.

```
cat(ifelse(substr(s <- strsplit(text, "\n")[[1]], 1, 1) %in% c("_", 0:9, " "), 
           paste0("# ", s), 
           gsub("[>] ", "", s)), 
    sep = "\n")
```

which results in

```
ddf2 = ddf[ddf$stone_ny>'stone',] # this is first command
ddf2[!duplicated(ddf2$deltnr),]   # second command
#    deltnr us stone_ny stone_mobility      
# 4    1536 63    stone         mobile 
# 10   1336 62    stone         mobile
```

The `"_"` and `0:9` are in there because one of the rules in R is that a function cannot begin with a `_` or a digit.  You can adjust it to fit your needs.

Comment: It works. I will try with other text copied from terminal also.

Comment: @rnso - `cat` also has a `labels` and an `fill` argument that might come in handy.  for example `cat(paste(letters, 10* 1:15), fill = TRUE, labels = paste0("{", 1:15, "}:"))`

Comment: I never bothered to look at the other arguments in `cat`. learn something new everyday!